# Can the node-oracledb add-on be used in an Oracle Mobile Hub Custom API?

Tags: node.js, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, node-oracledb

From within an Oracle Mobile Hub node.js Custom API I need to connect to an Oracle DB system instance (Basic authentication: username, password, public ip address, port, sid). Is it possible to use the node-oracledb add-on from within a Custom API? Is this the best way to connect to a remote Oracle db or is there a better mechanism from with Mobile Hub?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle Mobile Hub, but it appears to be related to Oracle Digital Assitant. https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/cloud/downloads/amce-downloads-4478270.html I downloaded the "ODA Samples v18.4.3.0 for Mobile Cloud Service" and didn't find a dependency on node-oracledb. Could you provide links to doc on what you're working with? Also, tell us more about your project, what do you mean by "custom API"? Finally, this post may be of interest: https://smatclouds.wordpress.com/2019/05/27/connect-oracle-digital-assistant-to-oracle-atp-database/

Comment: A Mobile Hub Custom API is basically a node.js module that handles GETs, POSTs, PUTs, DELETEs, etc. for a Mobile Hub Backend. You can see the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/mobile-hub/develop/custom-api-design.html#GUID-92703CA0-893D-4245-AF0E-A482886EBC95

Answer (score 1):

If I get your question correctly, you are asking if it's possible to have a custom component hosted in mobile hub accessing external Oracle db, if so he might want to explore the OIC ATP Adapter(https://blogs.oracle.com/integration/oic-integration-with-oracleatp) which you shall integrate to your Custom API as an external service. It's not possible to store the DB connection wallet within Mobile hub and the easiest work around would be to host the component on an external node container.

As Dan Mentioned, you might be interested to check how to do it here: https://smatclouds.wordpress.com/2019/05/27/connect-oracle-digital-assistant-to-oracle-atp-database/

Comment: I'm not using a Wallet for my Oracle db connection, I'm using Basic auth.